# Inno Setup: Delete folder with Task function

Tags: inno-setup

How can I delete a folder using a task function which must be executed when hitting Next button in Additional Task panel?

Thanks so much in advanced.

Comment: `[InstallDelete]` is the first section processed. Does it really need to be deleted when they click Next or just at the first stage of install? Making any changes before the setup starts is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether certain task is selected you can use the [`IsTaskSelected`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_istaskselected) function. So, to meet your requirement you can write something like this:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Tasks]
Name: deletefolder; Description: "Delete a folder"; GroupDescription: "Group Description:"

[Code]
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // allow the setup turning to the next page
  Result := True;
  // if we are on the Additional Tasks page and the task is selected, then...
  if (CurPageID = wpSelectTasks) and IsTaskSelected('deletefolder') then
    // here call the RemoveDir or DelTree function depending on your needs
end;
```

Comment: I'll try that later and let you know.

Comment: I've just tried and it works great! Thanks so much for your help again.

Comment: a doubt when inserting the code: if in DelTree I put the whole path (example: C:\test\*), it works corretly. But if I put ( DelTree('{app}\test\*'), it doesnt't work. I know I have to register the string of the path but I don't know how, or I think that's the problem. Any idea?

Comment: You forgot to `ExpandConstant`, `DelTree(ExpandConstant('{app}\test*'))` should be better ;-)

Comment: I don't know what I would do without you ;) Thanks